# bindToController directive with boolean display flag

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 directives that are embedded in another directive. The HTML for the "parent" directive looks like this:

```
show default: {{ controller.display.stripe }}

<div>
    <p ng-if="controller.display.stripe">Display default</p>
    <p ng-if="!controller.display.stripe">Do not display default</p>
</div>


<div apple-pay="controller.applePayAvailable(available)"></div>
<div stripe-pay ng-if="controller.display.stripe"></div>
```

As you can see, the **stripe-pay** directive is only displayed if **controller.display.stripe** is true. The boolean is initially set to false. Here is the controller for the **payments** directive:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('widget-directives').controller('PaymentsController', paymentsController);

    paymentsController.$inject = ['$scope']

    function paymentsController($scope) {
        var self = this;

        // Bindings
        self.display = {
            stripe: false
        };

        // Method binding
        self.applePayAvailable = applePayAvailable;
        self.checkout = checkout;

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////

        function applePayAvailable(available) {
            console.log('is apply pay available: ' + available);
            self.display.stripe = !available;
            console.log(self);
        };

        function checkout(e) {

            console.log('checking out');

            e.preventDefault();
        };
    };
})();
```

As you can see **self.display.stripe** is set to the opposite of whatever is returned from the child directive.
The console logs here are all reached and the `console.log(self)` shows the boolean as **true**, but the html `ng-if` are working as if the boolean is false.
I tried setting up a watch in the **PaymentsController** but it had no effect.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?
For reference, the **apple-pay** directive and controller looks like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('widget-directives').directive('applePay', applePay);

    function applePay() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            controller: 'ApplePayController',
            controllerAs: 'controller',
            bindToController: true,
            scope: {
                onCheckComplete: '&applePay'
            },
            templateUrl: 'app/directives/apple-pay/apple-pay.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                element.find('button').bind('click', controller.checkout);
            }
        };
    };
})();


(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('widget-directives').controller('ApplePayController', applePayController);

    applePayController.$inject = ['applePayService'];

    function applePayController(applePayService) {
        var self = this;

        console.log('should only be called once');

        // Method binding
        self.checkout = checkout;

        init();

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////

        function init() {
            applePayService.checkAvailability(setAvailability);
        };

        function setAvailability(available) {
            self.available = available === true;
            self.onCheckComplete({ available: self.available });
        };

        function checkout(e) {
            applePayService.checkout(e, onComplete, onError);
        };

        function onComplete(result, completion) {
            console.log(result, completion);
        };

        function onError(error) {
            self.error = error;
        };
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how `applePayService.checkAvailability` works, so I just call `setAvailability` with `false` parameter after `setAvailability` declaration, so in my case its working, `ng-if` is firing.

Buy you could try to wrap `applePayAvailable` with timeout apply

```
 function applePayAvailable(available) {
            setTimeout(function(){
              console.log('is apply pay available: ' + available);
              self.display.stripe = !available;
              console.log(self);
              $scope.$apply();
            }, 0)
        };
```

```js
    var app = angular.module('widget-directives', []);

    app.controller('PaymentsController', paymentsController);

    function paymentsController($scope) {
        var self = this;
        
        var controller = this;
        
        console.log('controller', controller)

        // Bindings
        self.display = {
            stripe: false
        };

        // Method binding
        self.applePayAvailable = applePayAvailable;
        

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////

        function applePayAvailable(available) {
            //setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('is apply pay available: ' + available);
            self.display.stripe = !available;
            console.log(self);
            //$scope.$apply();
            //}, 0)
        };

        function checkout(e) {

            console.log('checking out');

            e.preventDefault();
        };
    };

     app.directive('applePay', applePay);

    function applePay() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            controller: 'ApplePayController',
            controllerAs: 'controller',
            bindToController: true,
            scope: {
                onCheckComplete: '&applePay'
            },
            template: '<div></div>',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                console.log('scope', scope)
                element.find('button').bind('click', controller.checkout);
            }
        };
    };


   app.controller('ApplePayController', applePayController);


    function applePayController($scope) {
        var self = this;

        console.log('should only be called once', $scope);

        // Method binding
        //self.checkout = checkout;

        init();

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////

        function init() {
            //applePayService.checkAvailability(setAvailability);
        };

        function setAvailability(available) {
            self.available = available === true;
            $scope.onCheckComplete({ available: self.available });
        };
        
        setAvailability(false);


        function onComplete(result, completion) {
            console.log(result, completion);
        };

        function onError(error) {
            self.error = error;
        };
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div data-ng-app="widget-directives">
<div data-ng-controller="PaymentsController as controller">

show default: {{ controller.display.stripe }}

<div>
    <p ng-if="controller.display.stripe">Display default</p>
    <p ng-if="!controller.display.stripe">Do not display default</p>
</div>


<div apple-pay="controller.applePayAvailable(available)"></div>
<div stripe-pay ng-if="controller.display.stripe"></div>
<div ng-if="controller.display.stripe">Test ng-if with controller.display.stripe property </div>


</div>
</div>
```